# shutdown now vs shutdown -p now vs shutdown -h now vs poweroff

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, power-management, shutdown

There are lots of commands for PC shutdown. Which one is secure and which one should I choose for regular PC shutdown? Actually, I want to set a keyboard shortcut to off my PC. But I am confused about the command.

[image]

Comment: Read `man shutdown`

Comment: Also useful reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205464/whats-the-difference-between-poweroff-and-halt